# The tab called HELP in Excel quits after a time. Only RESTART Excel fixes it

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I'm running Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20100) 32-bit.  On this one, I have run SFC, DISM, have uninstalled MS365 and reinstalled it.

And, on another computer:
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 64-bit.  Both have the same problem.

I get development work going with Excel and, eventually will need one of the HELP tab ribbon functions.  Instead of getting the expected response, I get a message in the dialog that says:

> HELP
> Sorry, something went wrong.
> Please check your network connection and try again.

The network connection is fine.
Microsoft has been no help - just a big waste of time trying obvious things that I've already tried.

Can someone please suggest something that might be done?
With or without Microsoft?
It looks like a software bug.
I have uninstalled Office and reinstalled the latest version more than once.

Comment: You probably should edit your question and list what you have tried. Excel Help is working here on both production computers (Windows 11 Pro).

Comment: I don't know what to "try".  Excel Help does work here on multiple computers except when this anomaly appears.  I have gone through this with MS support twice but the apps still fail in this manner.  I cannot say how to duplicate the problem - as I have tried.  It seems like it is just time-dependent.  I beleive Excel works when first opened and this problem occurs some time later... when I need HELP of course.  I'm not at all sure what else might be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure what I could add if you have talked to Microsoft.  The Help function seems to be working here

Comment: Well, It works here too some of the time.....  Thanks for responding!